# Is there behind-the-scenes information on which came first, Bender's name, function or alcoholism?

Tags: futurama, names, character-development

Bender's name is a nice bit of wordplay because he is a bending unit, and also alcoholic (goes on benders).

But [this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bender_(Futurama)#Character)<sup>[1]</sup> in Wikipedia says he was named after the character John Bender from [The Breakfast Club](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Breakfast_Club).

So you have a triple conjunction:

- named after John **Bender** from the Breakfast Club
- goes on **benders**
- is a **bending** unit

Is there behind-the-scenes information of the evolution of the development of the character?  Which attributes came first?

[1]: "Intellectual Names". Sci-Fi Baby Names: 500 Out-of-this-world Baby Names from Anakin to Zardoz. p. 119

Comment: Are you *specifically, preferentially* looking for an out-of-universe answer?  I seem to recall an episode (in-universe) in which he says that he was named after his job; i.e., the function came first.  I have know idea what the writers were *thinking* when they wrote it.

Comment: @PeregrineRook:  I just don't think in universe is very interesting.   Especially for Futurama, it's whatever the writers happened to be thinking on that day.

Comment: Bender is fuelled by alcohol; he only gets drunk when he doesn't get enough. Also his real name is Rodriguez.

Comment: @Gaius I'm pretty sure it's Bender Bending Rodríguez.

Comment: @Praxis????????

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Yep, I'm here...working on it. ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the order is:

1. **Alcoholic**
2. **Named after John Bender from *The Breakfast Club***
3. **Bending Unit**

First of all, *Simpsons* and *Futurama* creator Matt Groening conceived of the character of Bender as the "Homer Simpson" of *Futurama*:

> **GROENING:**  And then there's Bender. And Bender's like -- he's the standout character right now on this show. **He's our robotic Homer Simpson.** He's just totally corrupt -- lovably corrupt -- a la Homer. **Loves his vices**. I think he's the first robot in science fiction who shoplifts

([Source](http://www.gotfuturama.com/Information/Articles/chat.dhtml))

*The Simpsons*, especially at the time, was an incredibly successful show, and therefore provided a model for projects such as *Futurama*.  Groening wanted a Homer-esque character in *Futurama* — a solid move of course, considering Homer's popularity — and coming with that were vices, particularly alcohol dependency.  It seems that the need to have such a character came before anything else.

[image]

Next up, Groening is known to be a big fan of *The Breakfast Club*.  As mentioned in the original question, the chapter "Intellectual Names" of the book *Sci-Fi Baby Names: 500 Out-of-This-World Baby Names from Anakin to Zardoz* cites Groening as saying that Bender's name is an homage to *Breakfast Club* character John Bender.   The name of course makes sense given the robot's alcoholism.   (Note that John Bender is also the source of Bart Simpson's familiar "Eat my shorts!" refrain.)

[image]

Once these attributes were in place, it was only natural to give the robot a role that fit the name: bending, specifically "Bending Unit 22".

## More evidence for this order

I decided to investigate early concept art as well.

Here is a sequence of sketches by Groening that eventually led to Bender as we now know him:

[image]

Notice that the sketches do not contain a name, whereas the analogous ones for other characters do.  For example, Fry was "Fry" from the beginning:

[image]

Leela's early sketches are also labelled prominently with her name.

What the Bender sketches emphasize is a Homer-esque character, particularly beginning with the bottom-left drawing of Bender as a short-order cook with Homer-like features.  Given that Groening's habit of labelling his sketches as soon as he has a name for them, it seems that Bender's name and function came later.